# duplicate ng-repeat in one table

Tags: json, angularjs

```
{
  "title": "hello"
  "fights": [{
    "round": "fights round 2",
    "teams" : [
    {
      "name": "teamA",
      "members": [
        {"name": "alex", "age": 31},
        {"name": "alex2", "age": 32}
      ]
    },{
      "name": "teamB",
      "members": [
        {"name":"niko", "age": 31}
        {"name":"niko2", "age": 32}
      ]
    }
    ]
  }, {
    "round": "fights round 2",
    "teams" : [
    {
      "name": "teamA2",
      "members": [
        {"name": "alex2", "age": 31},
        {"name": "alex22", "age": 32}
      ]
    },{
      "name": "teamB2",
      "members": [
        {"name":"niko2", "age": 31}
        {"name":"niko22", "age": 32}
      ]
    }
    ]
  }]
}
```

or see pastebin, http://pastebin.com/gfjU8ZiJ

now what I'm trying to do its to fetch the `title`,`round` and all the team members from each fight into one table, tr .. something like this

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="items in $root.fights">
        <td>{{item.title}}</td>
        <td>fightround2</td>
        <!-- and here to fetch all the members from each team -->
        <td>alex</td>
        <td>alex2</td>
        <td>niko</td>
        <td>niko2</td>
        <!-- here to fetch team from fights[1] -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

how can I make this done with ng-repeat ? unfortunately thats how the JSON comes and I can't change it, just read from it. thanks!

Comment: @Naqeeb, then can you give me any solution how make it done ?

Comment: @Naqeeb ng-repeat works with object also. I think you need to read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Hmm, I didnt gave a good example, sec i'll re-edit it, because there can be also 2 fights and they all need to be fetched in one row in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you HTML to following

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="items in $root.fights track by $index">
        <td>{{item.title}}</td>
        <td>fightround2</td>
        <td ng-repeat="member in getTeamMembers(item)">{{member.name}}</td>
        <!-- and here to fetch all the members from each team -->
        <td>alex</td>
        <td>alex2</td>
        <td>niko</td>
        <td>niko2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Add this to your controller

```
$scope.getTeamMembers = function (item) {
    var members = [];

    for (var i=0; i < item.fights.length; i++) {
        var fight = item.fights[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < fight.teams.length; j++){
            var team = fight.teams[j];
            for(var k=0; k < team.members.length; k++) {
                Array.prototype.push.apply(members, team.members[k]);
            }
        }
    }

    return members;
};
```

Comment: this one its just fetching the teams into one **TD** and give me something like `<td>"alex""alex2""niko""niko2"</td>`

Comment: like each name(memebers.name) in separated `<td>`

Comment: edited my answer. You need a function to club all members together.